How to Configure Query Timeout in Data API Builder for GraphQL Queries?
I’m experiencing an issue with my GraphQL API using Azure's Data API Builder. Whenever a user runs a query that takes longer than 30 seconds, the query times out.
I used ChatGPT, but the suggestions provided did not align with the current capabilities or documentation of Data API Builder. Specifically, there was confusion around setting a queryTimeout in the configuration file (dab-config.json), which I couldn't find any official reference to.
My current configuration (dab-config.json) looks like this:
Copy code
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/download/v0.9.7/dab.draft.schema.json",
  "data-source": {
    "database-type": "mssql",
    "connection-string": "xxxxx",
    "options": {
      "set-session-context": false
    }

Could you provide guidance on where to find the settings for adjusting the timeout duration? Specifically, which file should I modify to change this behavior?
expect to make a bigger querytimeout so user with more than 30 secondes query could work ;)

could please your  GraphQL API  code in text formate in the above question

What is the query that you are executing?

You can set it in the connection string directly. Which is part of the configuration file
 "database-type": "mssql",
 "connection-string": "xxxxx",

